# Count of a string returns a string value in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

When I run the code below I get this error message in BigQuery:

> Error: Argument type mismatch in function DIVIDE:
>   'total_no_of_bounces' is type string, 'Alias_Name' is type string

Can anyone help me with it?

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT
  trafficSource.source,
  ( ( 'total_no_of_bounces' / 'Alias_Name' ) * 100 ) AS bounce_rate
FROM (
  SELECT
    trafficSource.source,
    COUNT(trafficSource.source ) AS Alias_Name,
    COUNT ( totals.bounces ) AS total_no_of_bounces
  FROM
    [86958781.ga_sessions_intraday_20160617]
  WHERE
    totals.pageviews = 1
  GROUP BY
    trafficSource.source)
GROUP BY
  trafficSource.source,
  bounce_rate ;
```

Comment: try changing the line to ( ( total_no_of_bounces / Alias_Name ) * 100 ) AS bounce_rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove quotes in below

```
 'total_no_of_bounces' / 'Alias_Name'
```

So it will be

```
 total_no_of_bounces / Alias_Name
```

and the whole query will be

```
SELECT
  trafficSource.source,
  ( ( total_no_of_bounces / Alias_Name ) * 100 ) AS bounce_rate
FROM (
  SELECT
    trafficSource.source,
    COUNT(trafficSource.source ) AS Alias_Name,
    COUNT ( totals.bounces ) AS total_no_of_bounces
  FROM
    [86958781.ga_sessions_intraday_20160617]
  WHERE
    totals.pageviews = 1
  GROUP BY
    trafficSource.source)
GROUP BY
  trafficSource.source,
  bounce_rate ;
```